# html css drag drop hover bug?

Tags: javascript, css, html, drag-and-drop, hover

I have implemented drag and drop on one part of my page where I drag an element onto a canvas.  This works fine, but on a completely different part of the page where I have implemented a css hover the hover effect get's activated.  The html structure for this part of the page is....

```
        <div class="horizMenu" id="frames" style="width:700px " >
            <!--Frame mini Canvases will be inserted here  -->
            <span id="NewFrameInputSpan"> 
                <ul id="NewFrameInputUL" >New Frame
                    <li  onmouseup="window.alert('?');">Empty</li>
                    <li onmouseup="window.alert('?');">Copy</li>
                    <li onmousedown="window.alert('hi');" onmouseup="window.alert(e)">Smart</li>
                </ul>
            </span>
        </div>
```

And the CSS for this is

```
.horizMenu{
    color:#93a1a1; 
    background-color:#fdf6e3;   
}
.horizMenu span{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
}
#NewFrameInputSpan{
    bottom: 1.5px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.horizMenu:hover #NewFrameInputSpan{ opacity: 1;  }
```

How is it that a javascrit drag and drop from two different elements could cause a hover event to trigger in a completely different 3rd element.  All these elements are siblings BTW, and not parents/children of each other.  This hover effect is triggered when I release the hover (mouse up).  Notice I added the onmouseup/onmousesdown alerts to the li elements.  They don't get called.  This only seems to happen on Safari/Chrome but not on Opera (haven't tried others).  Are there any known issue with drag and drop in webkit?

Comment: Still seeing this effect in Safari 10.0.2

Answer (score 0):

<del>Well I solved my problem, but only through a hacky work around.  I wrap my div in a div and then gate pointer-events to make sure that mouse input is only accept when the mouse is actually over the div...</del>

```
<div onmouseover="document.getElementById('frames').style.pointerEvents = 'auto';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('frames').style.pointerEvents = 'none';"  >
     <div class="horizMenu"  id="frames" style="width:700px; pointer-events:none; "   >
         <!--My Content here-->
     </div>
</div>
```

<del>This doesn't stop the errant drop events from hitting my div, it just make my div ignore them.  If anyone has a better solution I'd like to here it.</del>

Sadly, this doesn't actually fix my issue like I thought it did.  It persists.